# Save dictionary to Json file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this

```
mydict = {
          'Math': [['geometry'], 300],
          'Science' : [['physics'], 24],
          'Business':[['Management'], 101] }
```

I want to create a brand new json file, with this dictionary.

So far i have

```
def json_test():
    with open("example.json", "w") as myfile:
      json.dump({mydict}, myfile)
```

This gives me an error of unhashable type: 'dict'.

Comment: That's because you put `{`, `}` around `mydict`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mydict` is already a dict. Just leave the `{`, `}` out:

```
def json_test():
    with open("example.json", "w") as myfile:
        json.dump(mydict, myfile)
```